# How do I run a test in Django using production data (Read only)?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unit-testing

I would like to run a test in Django but in order to run the test I need access to data from the production database (I don't want to setup an entirely new database for testing).

How can use this data from the production database without allowing write access in my script? I don't want this test to effect anything, but I need access to this data in order to run this test. It seems ridiculous to have to launch (and pay for) an entirely new database just to grab a few rows of data, any advice?

Comment: Why don't you want to set up a testing database?

Comment: It just seems weird to pay for and maintain two database and keep them in sync, wouldn't it be much easier to just read from production if thats all I need?

Comment: If you don't care about your production data, then maybe it would be easier for you as a developer, but no organization would knowingly let a developer run tests against production.  It's also illegal to do if your database contains PII on EU citizens...  Setting up a testing environment is pretty fundamental, no?

Comment: use fixtures from your prod db, and let them be loaded into a test machine local sqlite test db. Isnt this safer?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend against doing this. You will not have full control over the state of the database when running tests, and the passing of a test might depend on the contents of the production database. And it will be impossible to test edge cases before they occur. Not to mention that if you mess something up you run the risk of populating your production database with test data or destroying records from your production database.

Django makes creating test databases very simple. When using the command `python manage.py test [app_name]` a test database will be created for you with the same settings as your production/development database.

To get this functionality, the Django test docs state:

> If your tests rely on database access such as creating or querying models, be sure to create your test classes as subclasses of django.test.TestCase rather than unittest.TestCase.

Here's more on the Django test database: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database

Regarding your concern about maintaining a test database, Django spins up the database before the tests are rune and destroys the database after the tests have finished. The test database is also created on your local machine (assuming you run it on your local machine). So I don't think pricing should be an issue.

**Edit:**
On populating the test database before tests:

**1.** Create instances within a test before the test logic starts. These will be destroyed when the test finishes. Example:

```
class Tester(TestCase):
    def test_works(self):
        instance = Model.create(data=data)
        # then run your test logic
```

or

**2.** Create instances in the `setUp` method of a test class. Everything in `setUp` will be (re)created before each test method of the class and destroyed after each test completes. Example:

```
class Tester(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.instance = Model.create(data=data)

    def test_works(self):
        # run test logic with access to self.instance
```

or

**3.** Using fixtures to populate before tests are run. Define data for some instances of your Models in the `fixtures` directory within whatever app you're testing in (directory will probably need to be created). You can define them in json or yaml and I'm sure other formats. Then in your tests:

```
class Tester(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        fixtures = ['/myapp/fixtures/dump.json']

    def test_works(self):
        # test logic and you can access all the instances created from the data in dump.json
```

More on fixtures: https://django-testing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fixtures.html

If you want your test db to have data similar to your production database, you can pull data from the production database and save it in a fixture.

Comment: But the test database doesn't populate with any data, every time I run queries on a test database I spin up the results are empty?

Comment: @superdee correct and that's really a feature because you will have full and explicit control over the db's contents and your tests will be more independent. In each test you can create some objects or do so in the `setUp` method of the test class or use fixtures.

Comment: Can I populate the test database with data thats already in the production database? Is this what a fixture are, right now I've been creating and saving models by hand but it would be nice to populate the data in the test database from the production database instead of copy and pasting each row

Comment: @superdee I just made an edit to the post that I think somewhat addresses that. Just find a way to dump data from your production db into json format (or similar). Then store it in a fixture.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with others that this is a bad idea for various reason. If you want to move forward with it anyway, set up a separate database user with read-only permissions. How you do this depends on the database server you are using.

Double check that you are actually using the credentials of the read-only user in your tests.

Comment: As an addendum, the system check framework might be a more appropriate tool to run "tests" against the live DB.  It also indicates that, in contrast to most of the answers here, it's not a bad idea in the slightest: it's built right into the framework.